# Spiral with narrowing / tapered line in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am desperately trying to make a spiral (see picture below) narrowing out at the end. The line should be thick at the beginning and become very thin at the end. It should be a very smooth transition. I tried brushes, which works well but it does unfortunately NOT work with a gradient. And I need to apply a gradient on my object. The width tool does not work as well (see pictures below), as it seems to work only between anchor points (although I have joined the pathes...). How can I reach my goal to have a tapered spiral with a gradient applied on it?

Many thanks for your much appreciated comments.

Best regards,
Silvan

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I worked with this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC3oVwYehd0

Comment: What didn't work? You need same spring with similar gradient but it should keep getting narrower?

Comment: Width tool seems work fine, if I correctly understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: And gradient can't be applied on strokes with brushes.

Comment: Do you need something like this? https://imgur.com/KAPTdyR

Comment: Err. Width tool works anywhere on the curve.

Comment: Please see my comment below. Size tool unfortunately doesnt work well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not need the *actual* Width Tool.

You can simply set a **Stroke Profile** in the **Stroke Panel** for many things. Then use the Width Tool if you wish to refine further.

[image]

Comment: wow, It is super quick!

Comment: Ahhhh !!! JUST what I needed :) upvoted

Answer (score 3):

Like you said, gradients don't work on a stroke with art brush. However, width tool seems to work fine to me:

[image]

---

I can reproduce your problem following way. Applying a small amount of Width tool somewhere middle of path or near one end, and then applying it at extreme end:

[image]

**EDIT - After checking the OP's open file, I found this:**

Here's what was causing problem:

[image]

As you can see, two anchor points were going in opposite directions and once I moved them in 'proper' place, Width tool worked throughout the stroke. You will need to find and fix all those anchor points. I guess the they weren't joined properly in first place. So it caused problems.

---

Another way of doing this is by making a raster image like this and add it to art brushes and then applying it to your stroke:

[image]

But it will have some limitations like you might not get smooth result and you won't be able to edit colors.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I dont know why but width tool doesnt work with my form (see pictures below). It changes only size between anchor points. Why is that?

Comment: @Silvan I think the problem with your path is they are not joined. Are they two seperate paths?

Comment: I posted a picture few seconds ago. I marked all the paths, went to object -> path -> join. but it doesnt work with the width tool...

Comment: I'll check and udpate

Comment: @Silvan Did you apply the width tool by mistake (negligible amount) in the middle of your spring path? Somewhere near the end? That can also cause a problem. You might have done with mistake? Can you try using your original sprint stroke (make sure no width tool is applied) and then try width tool at one end.

Comment: If possible, can you share your open file somewhere? (if this is not your main project file and just a test file and contains nothing else)

Comment: The only way I can reproduce your problem is by applying a small amount of width tool somewhere near the end of stroke, and then applying it extreme end.

Comment: yes would be great. I will share it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127891/discussion-between-vikas-and-silvan).